# Prestashop translating a module error occurs

Tags: prestashop

as the title says, when I try to translate a module (any module in any language), this error message appears in a blank screen: ***[an error occurred while processing this directive]***

What are the probably causes of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The specific PHP options and directives may be disabled, causing this error.